# Awk remove field only if numeric

Tags: sed, awk

When I use this command:

```
ls /var/log/packages/*SBo|cut -d / -f 5
```

it returns this:

```
webcore-fonts-3.0-noarch-3_SBo
winetricks-20120923-noarch-1_SBo
wireshark-1.12.1-x86_64-1_SBo
wxGTK-2.8.12-x86_64-3_SBo
```

I want to remove everything starting from a numeric field (the rest of the lines should be omitted). So I want it to look like:

```
webcore-fonts
winetricks
wireshark
wxGTK
```

How to do this? I think `awk` is perfect, but I don't know how to delete the rest of the lines (but only if numeric).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
ls /var/log/packages/*SBo| sed 's/-[0-9].*//'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done with `sed`:

```
$ ls /var/log/packages/*SBo | sed -r 's|.*/||; s/-[[:digit:]][[:digit:].]*-.*//'
webcore-fonts
winetricks
wireshark
wxGTK
```

Explanation:

- `-r`

  This enables extended regular expressions which reduce the number of escapes needed.
- `s|.*/||`

  This removes the directories that precede the file name.
- `s/-[[:digit:]][[:digit:].]*-.*//`

  This looks a number surrounded by dashes and removes it and everything that follows.  The regex uses `[:digit:]` instead of `[0-9]` to assure that it works in all locales and with extended character sets.

On Mac OSX, try:

```
ls /var/log/packages/*SBo | sed -E -e 's|.*/||' -e 's/-[[:digit:]][[:digit:].]*-.*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a Bourne-like shell this way:

```
for Package in /var/log/packages/*SBo;do
    Package="$(basename $Package)"
    echo "${Package%%-[0-9]*}"
done
```

This makes use of [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove from the name of the package anything after the first occurrence of `-` followed by a digit followed by anything else.

And if your locale has digits not captured by `[0-9]`, the `[[:digit:]]` trick used in [John1024's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164698/26909) works here, too. That is,

```
for Package in /var/log/packages/*SBo;do
    Package="$(basename $Package)"
    echo "${Package%%-[[:digit:]]*}"
done
```

also works.

Answer (score 1):

If your files can contain fancy characters in names as spaces, or simple you don't like the idea of parsing the `ls` command, then you can use `find` instead:

```
find /var/log/packages -maxdepth 1 -name '*SBo' -exec sh -c 'sed s,.*/,,\;s/-[[:digit:]].*//<<<"$0"' {} \;
```